# C# WindowsForm Как реализовать список действий, которые должна выполнять программа и добавление в этот список действий по шаблону?

Tags: c#

Я еще новичок в программировании и объясню так, как я это понимаю.

У меня есть библиотека для управления CAN-интерфейсом и я хочу написать приложение, которое взаимодействует с этим CAN-интерфейсом.

Вопрос в следующем. Я хочу сделать так чтоб в приложении можно было реализовать события.

Под словом "событие" я имею ввиду 2 шаблона команды для CAN-интерфейса, а именно:

1. Название "Отправить сообщение". Параметры которые нужно будет вписать в этот шаблон: "ID" "Data[8]"
2. Название "Отследить прием сообщения". Параметры которые нужно будет вписать в этот шаблон: "ID" "Data[8]", "Время которое ожидать сообщение", "Если пришло то...", "Если не пришло то..."
3. Название "Отследить прием сигнала". Параметры которые нужно будет вписать в этот шаблон: "ID" "Data[8]", "Время которое ожидать сигнал", "Если пришло то...", "Если не пришло то..."

Как реализовать цепочку которая будет обрабатывать эти шаблоны и проверять выполнено ли действие?

Объясняю действия пользователя:

1. Открывает приложение
2. Нажимает добавить событие : Отправить кан сообщение ID-... Data-[...]
3. Нажимает добавить событие : Отследить прием сообщения ID-... Data-[...] Время ожидания 500мс Если пришло, то записать результат "Сообщение пришло". Если не пришло, записать результат "Сообщение не пришло"
4. Проверяет какой результат выдало приложение.

Я реализовал прием и оправку сообщения, но вот как сделать именно цепочку, которая будет выполняться не понимаю))

Comment: То, что у вас уже получилось, приложите к своему вопросу и можете подсветить где попытка того, что не получается. Если такой нет, то то, что получилось.

Comment: Создаете интерфейс, который будет иметь в себе общие свойства команд, например, ID, название, описание, параметры, действие. Далее под каждую команду создаете свой класс, прописывая там всю логику. После, создаете коллекцию, которая будет хранить в себе все эти классы, ну и заполняете ее всеми доступными командами. В интерфейсе пользователю выводите этот список для выбора. Ну а цепочка, по аналогии, делаете класс, в котором будет коллекция команд, id, название, и т.д, далее делаете коллекцию этого класса, которую уже пользователь заполнит.